# How to extract certain rows satisfying a condition?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have three columns - P1,P2,M and 411935 rows. I want to extract only those rows which satisfy P1>=P2>=0.25*M. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = Pick[DATA, 
  Table[p1[[i]] >= p2[[i]] >= 0.25*M[[i]], {i, 411935}]]
```

Thank you all for sharing your ideas. I used the above by combining your ideas and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select[yourTable, #[[1]]>=#[[2]]>=(0.25*#[[3]])&]
```

Answer (score 2):

If runtime is a major concern to you, you could use this `Pick` along with vectorized integer arithmetic instead:

```
yourTable = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {411935, 3}];
aa = Select[
      yourTable, 
      #[[1]] >= #[[2]] >= (0.25*#[[3]]) &
      ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
bb = Pick[
      yourTable,
      Times@@UnitStep[Differences[{0.25,1.,1.} Transpose[yourTable][[{3,2,1}]]]],
      1
      ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
aa == bb
```

> 0.76
>
> 0.0142
>
> True

If your columns are already given as vector `P1`, `P2`, and `M`, then you can skip the costly transposition to get the transposed result of the above:

```
{P1, P2, M} = Transpose[yourTable];
(
   picker = UnitStep[Subtract[P1, P2]] UnitStep[Subtract[P2, 0.25 M]];
   {nP1, nP2, nM} = Map[Pick[#, picker, 1] &, {P1, P2, M}];
   ) // RepeatedTiming // First

{nP1, nP2, nM} == Transpose[bb]
```

> 0.0075
>
> True

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation of @Henrik's [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick) approach that avoids [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose):

```
cc = Pick[
    yourTable,
    UnitStep[yourTable . {{1,0}, {-1,1}, {0,-.25}}] . {1,1},
    2
]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.010, Null}

Compare to his answer:

```
bb = Pick[
    yourTable,
    Times@@UnitStep[Differences[{0.25,1.,1.} Transpose[yourTable][[{3,2,1}]]]],
    1
]; // RepeatedTiming

bb === cc
```

> {0.020, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Ah, very good improvement, indeed! In particular, I pretty much like how you replaced `Times` by a `Dot`. Plus, this is much short to type.^^

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Exactly. I saw those `Times` operations, and thought figuring out how to use `Dot` instead should provide a nice speed up.

Comment: Surprisingly, I found that `picker = UnitStep[P1 - P2] + UnitStep[P2 - 0.25 M];
{nP1, nP2, nM} = Map[Pick[#, picker, 2] &, {P1, P2, M}];` is _not_ faster than `picker = UnitStep[P1 - P2] UnitStep[P2 - 0.25 M];
{nP1, nP2, nM} = Map[Pick[#, picker, 1] &, {P1, P2, M}];` on my machine. But anyways, the `Dot ` saves a transposition.